# Macbook Pro Retina 15" (mid 2012) screen is glitching in specific situations

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, display

The display of my macbook is glitching as you can see in image below. However this is happening only if I'm trying to do some on graphics heavy tasks, just like opening big Rhinoceros project. The second occasion is when I wake up computer (from Sleep mode) and it was NOT pluged in. This glitching stops after a while, but it is at least disconcerting.

Does anyone have any advice?

[image: Display flickering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely your MacBook has a defective GPU. You are lucky however, since there is a [recall](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) for your specific model.

Check your eligibility [here](https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do) and contact AppleCare.

Comment: Thank you, for advice! Unfortunately, after filling serial number it asks for date of purchasing and then pops upt this: We're sorry, but we are unable to complete your request at this time. Please try again later. I've tried it yeasterday and also today, nothing changed :( I have also run apple hardware test, (the extended one) and no issues showed. Weird.

Comment: It is known that the hardware test does not necessarily find the issue. Try again later or simply call or bring it to a store...

Comment: Yes, I was there, but I was not able to leave there my macbook for 2 days. I will probably have to do it so. Thank you for help ;)